# Is the following expression (on limit behaviours) correct?

Tags: limits, computational-complexity

$$\frac{18n^4 + \mathcal{O}(n^2)}{2(n^2 + n)} \in \Omega\Big(\frac{18n^4 + \mathcal{O}(n^2)}{9n^2 - 3n}\Big).$$

I never had to analyse the limit behaviour of a function which describes itself a limit behaviour.

I don't know whether the above expression is:

1. correct
2. trivial
3. elegant

In the above I refer to $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{O}$ respectively as
$$\Omega(g(n)) = \{f(n)\ |\ \exists{c, n_0 \in \mathbb{N}^\texttt{+}} :\ 0 \leq g(n) < c\cdot f(n),\ \forall n \geq n_0\},$$
$$\mathcal{O}(g(n)) = \{f(n)\ |\ \exists{c, n_0 \in \mathbb{N}^\texttt{+}}\ :\ 0 \leq f(n) < c\cdot{}g(n),\ \forall n \geq n_0\}.$$

May I have some hint?

Comment: Your definition of $f\in\Omega(g)$ is strange, it seems to be equivalent to [$g\in o(f)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation).

Comment: I use the Knoth notation where $f \in \Omega(g) \iff g \in \mathcal{O}(f)$.

Comment: What you wrote in your post is not equivalent to Knuth's definition.

Comment: What if $f$ and $g$ are known to be polynomials like in my case?

Comment: That makes no difference: even for polynomials, $o(f)\subsetneq\mathcal O(f)$.

Comment: Sorry, but they look equivalent to me, up to switching $<$ and $\leq$ symbols and $g$ and $f$ functions.

Comment: $n\in \mathcal O(n)$, $n\notin o(n)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139643/discussion-between-daniele-cuomo-and-anne-bauval).

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Is the following expression correct?" says nothing about the subject of the question. It's a useless title.

Comment: Done. Hope it is fine now.

Comment: Actually, I retract my comment on $\Omega$-notation. The condition $\forall{c \in \mathbb{N}^\texttt{+}},\ \exists{n_0 \in \mathbb{N}}\ :\ 0 \leq c\cdot{}g(n) \leq f(n),\ \forall n \geq n_0$ seems more like the Hardy-Littlewood type: for example, it prevents $n \in \Omega(n)$, since for $c = 2$ we will never have $0 \leq 2n \leq n$ no matter how big $n$ is.  For Knuth's definition, we want $\exists{c, n_0 \in \mathbb{N}^\texttt{+}}\ :\ 0 \leq g(n) < c\cdot{}f(n),\ \forall n \geq n_0$: the mirror of the definition of $\mathcal O(g)$.

Comment: Thank you. Are you using your definition in your answer?

Comment: @DanieleCuomo All my answer does is simplify the nested asymptotics to a standard question of checking whether $\frac{18n^4}{2(n^2 + n)} \in \Omega\left(\frac{19n^4}{9n^2 - 3n}\right)$, which you can do by any definition you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the nested $\mathcal O(n^2)$ inside the $\Omega$ is unusual to say the least, but in this case it does not matter. For any $f \in \mathcal O(n^2)$, there is an $n_0 \in \mathbb N^+$ such that for $n \ge n_0$, $0 \le f(n) \le n^2$, which will mean that $0 \le f(n) \le n^4$. At this point, we have
$$
\frac{18n^4}{2(n^2 + n)} \le \frac{18n^4 + \mathcal{O}(n^2)}{2(n^2 + n)} \le \frac{19n^4}{2(n^2 + n)}
$$
and
$$
\frac{18n^4}{9n^2 - 3n} \le \frac{18n^4 + \mathcal{O}(n^2)}{9n^2 - 3n} \le \frac{19n^4}{9n^2 - 3n}
$$
so, up to a constant, we don't care about the $\mathcal O(n^2)$ anymore.

*(Fine print: the $\mathcal O(n^2)$'s in the two parts of the expression might be different, so in general there are two thresholds $n \ge n_0$ and $n \ge n_1$ that we have to surpass. But this is fine, since it's always enough to just consider $n \ge \max\{n_0, n_1\}$.)*

At this point, since $f \in \Omega(g)$ is a lower bound on $f$, it's enough to take the lower bound for one fraction and the upper bound for the other: we will be done if we prove
$$
   \frac{18n^4}{2(n^2 + n)} \in \Omega\left(\frac{19n^4}{9n^2 - 3n}\right).
$$
(Of course, the $18$ and $19$ are both constant factors, and won't affect our work.) This is now a standard exercise in $\Omega$-notation.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean with "if we prove". It looks proved to me by your reasoning.

Comment: 1) What my reasoning shows is that proving $\frac{18n^4}{2(n^2 + n)} \in \Omega\left(\frac{19n^4}{9n^2 - 3n}\right)$ is *equivalent* to proving the statement in the question; I have not compared the two functions at all. That is still left to do.

Comment: 2) Since we do not know the anonymous $\mathcal O(n^2)$ functions, we cannot give an explicit threshold $n \ge \max\{n_0, n_1\}$; it might be very large if one of them is $10^{100} n^2$, and small if they are just $n^2$. The point is that since a threshold like that exists, we don't have to think about it, since the final $f \in \Omega(g)$ type statement we have to prove will also have a threshold in it.

Answer (score 2):

Split it as $\frac{18n^4}{2(n^2 + n)} + \frac{O(n^2)}{2(n^2 + n)}$. The first term is $\sim 9n^2 = \Theta(n^2)$. The absolute
value of the second term is for large $n$ less than or equal to $\frac{Cn^2}{2(n^2 + n)} \to C/2$, so the second term is $O(1)$. Thus the total is $\sim 9n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of $\Omega$ being now that of Knuth, it translates by a flip to the less ambiguous notation $\mathcal O$. All our sequences will be $>0$, to not bother about absolute values.

First recall that if $a_n\sim\lambda b_n$ and $c_n\sim\mu d_n$ for some constants $\lambda,\mu>0$, then $a\in\mathcal O(c)\iff b\in\mathcal O(d)$. The original question (correct but not so elegant)
$$\frac{18n^4 + \mathcal O(n^2)}{9n^2 - 3n}\in\mathcal O\left(\frac{18n^4 + \mathcal O(n^2)}{2(n^2 + n)}\right)?$$
thus simplifies to
$$\frac{n^4}{n^2}\in\mathcal O\left(\frac{n^4}{n^2}\right)?$$
which is trivial.

The simplification of each of the $\mathcal O$'s (in the two numerators) was legit because $18n^4+u_n\sim 18 n^4$ for *any* $u\in\mathcal O(n^2)$.